# Liferay 6.2 CE-GA6 make NTLM work for chrome and firefox?

Tags: java, liferay, single-sign-on, liferay-6, ntlm

I have configured NTLM for single sign on in my application which is working fine on Internet Explorer but not on chrome and firefox.There is a restriction in Liferay source code which restricts NTLM only for IE. Is there any way I can remove that restriction?

Note: Chrome and Firefox themselves support NTLM, it is Liferay side issue.[Also asked this question here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/93201745)

Comment: If only you'd have linked your crossposts, so that the volunteers attempting to answer your question wouldn't need to do all the research by themselves that has already been brought up in other places. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site and act on it

Comment: @OlafKock updated the question according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in a source code i think, you can just remove `BrowserSnifferUtil.isIe(request)` condition from `if` statements in NtlmFiler.java and form NtlmPostFilter.java. Create ext plugin and make changes

Comment: this leads me to this which actually helped me solving my problem -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915136/how-to-override-portal-impl-jar-classes-in-liferay-ext-plugin