# How to override portal-impl jar classes in Liferay ext-plugin

Tags: java, spring, liferay, liferay-6, ntlm

I want to override two portal-impl.jar classes **NtlmFiler.java** and **NtlmPostFilter.java**, I have created an ext-plugin project and placed my custom written classes in ext-impl/src but I am unable to configure my spring.xml file to use my newly written classes instead of portal-impl classes, maybe i am totally wrong about doing it this way.

My ext-spring.xml code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
<bean id="com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmFilter"
    class="com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmFilter">
    <property name="ntlmFilter">
        <bean class="com.sso.ntlm.filter.CustomNtlmFilter">
            <property name="CustomNtlmFilter" ref="customNtlmFilter" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter"
    class="com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter">
    <property name="ntlmPostFilter">
        <bean class="com.sso.ntlm.filter.CustomNtlmPostFilter">
            <property name="CustomNtlmPostFilter" ref="customNtlmPostFilter" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note: [The idea is to solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877164/liferay-6-2-ce-ga6-make-ntlm-work-for-chrome-and-firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `NtlmFilter` is no Spring bean, there is no use to define it in `ext-spring.xml`.

See `portal.properties`:

```
# ... and the filter
# com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmFilter must be referenced
# in web.xml.
```

So you just need to reference your filter class instead in `liferay-web.xml` or `web-ext.xml` (I don't know if the later works for overrides).

The same applies to the `NtlmPostFilter`.